# Creating a New TXT Document within a Newly-Created Folder

Tags: applescript, folders, file

I'm building an Applescript that currently creates a new finder folder inside a certain folder:

```
tell application "Finder"
activate
make new folder at folder "RecUp Memos" of folder "Dropbox" of folder "Jimmbo" of folder "Users" of startup disk
end tell
```

I don't name the folder because I want the result to be "untitled folder [x+1]".

Next step is to create, name, and save a new blank TXT document inside that new folder. Can anyone help?

Comment: Unless there is a particular reason to use BBEdit, an easy way is to use `touch` in a `do shell script`.  What have you done so far?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "BBEdit document". There are only files with extension types for which BBEdit is the default app. So *IF* you've associated BBEdit as the default app for .txt files, then you can add a .txt file.

Comment: I removed the BBEdit reference and showed the script thus far

Answer (score 0):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code*, as is, works for me in **macOS High Sierra**:

```
set thisFile to "foobar.txt"
set thisFolder to (path to home folder) & "Dropbox:RecUp Memos:" as string

tell application "Finder" to set foo to (make new folder at alias thisFolder) as alias

do shell script "touch " & quoted form of (POSIX path of foo) & thisFile
```

**NOTE:** As *coded*, the *fully qualified pathname* of `thisFolder` must already exist.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).</sub>

Comment: I can't stipulate the file path of the folder because it's not known. This is the roadblock I'm trying to work around.

Comment: @Jimmbo, My answer expressly answers the question you asked and nowhere in your OP did you express "I can't stipulate the file path of the folder because it's not known. This is the roadblock I'm trying to work around. "

Comment: I said:"I don't name the folder because I want the result to be "untitled folder [x+1]"."

Comment: @Jimmbo, By not declaring the _name_ of the _folder_ it creates a _folder_ named "untitled folder" and if run again then "untitled folder 2" and then "untitled folder 3", etc. If this is not what you want then you need to clarify explicitly and specifically what you mean by "I don't name the folder because I want the result to be "untitled folder [x+1]"." !

Comment: I want to create "untitled folder", "untitled folder 2", "untitled folder 3", etc, as I said, and as you confirmed. But this leaves me unable to stipulate the folder for the second part of the script.

Comment: @Jimmbo, What second part of the script? There is no second part of the script shown in the OP! Again, you need to clarify explicitly and specifically what you want to do. If you you do not edit your OP and make it clear what it is you need then I'm not sure how you expect any help.

Comment: Part 1: create new folder
Part 2: create txt doc in folder

Comment: @Jimmbo, RE: "Part 1: create new folder Part 2: create txt doc in folder" ... Did you even run the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ I posted? It does exactly that, creates the `untitled folder` _folder_ (incremented as necessary) at the location **you** provided in the _code_ of your OP, and then creates an empty text file within the _folder_ created! Unless you edit your OP and provide all details relevant to what you're trying to do and be explicit and specific about it then the only and last thing I have to say is modify the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ to fit your needs!